# How to Configure SSL on Apache 2.4

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4

This is really very confusing, there are a lot of guides available for configuring SSL but I am stuck and confused about what should I follow.

I have a fresh server.

- ubuntu 18.04
- Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- Server built:   2020-08-12T21:33:25

Configured virtual host as follows and it is working fine on HTTP

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have received a zip file containing the following files.

1. aXXXXXX.crt
2. aXXXXXX.pem
3. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Copied those received files at /etc/apache2/ssl

Configured as:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
        
        <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/aXXXXXX.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/aXXXXXX.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

No error, syntax OK.

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

But when I reload my apache2 config

Following command run fine reload apache configs, but site stopped working.

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

It crashes apache service :-(

What am I doing wrong, please guide

**Updates:**

`aXXXXXX.crt` the first line is `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

```
openssl x509 -in aXXXXXX.crt -noout -text
```

> X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: returns my valid domain name

`aXXXXXX.pem` the first line is `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` not `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

```
openssl rsa -in aXXXXXX.pem -noout -text
```

OUTPUT:

```
unable to load Private Key
140489527252288:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

These all 3 total files, there is no other certificate.

Comment: You should have the key file from when the certificate signing request was generated.  That's not typically something GoDaddy is going to send you. (the whole point of a PRIVATE key is that only you have access to it)

Comment: Please suggest who will provide me that key? What step is missing? Should I ask my SSL provider to provide me something else needed/missing?

Comment: Whoever got the certificate for you (it sounds like you didn't personally do this) should have the private key. Or if you recall doing a command like `openssl req -newkey . . .` and entering things like your city, state, common name, etc. the key should have been generated during that step.

Comment: Please provide me a full command and if I generate the key this way, will it work?

Comment: If you generate a new key, you will also have to have the certificate authority (apparently GoDaddy, in this case) sign a new certificate signing request (CSR) and get a new certificate.  It may or may not be easier to locate the original key -- it could have just been a simple human error that you didn't also receive the key file.

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks fine, so you should check that those files are what you think they are.

- aXXXXXX.crt should be a certificate file.

  - Check that the first line is `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.
  - Run `openssl x509 -in aXXXXXX.crt -noout -text` and check that the output looks right for your server. Look especially at the "Subject" and "x509v3 Subject Alternative Name" fields.
- aXXXXXX.pem should be a private key file.

  - Check that the first line is `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.
  - Run `openssl rsa -in aXXXXXX.pem -noout -text`. The first line should say "RSA Private-Key".
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt should be a certificate chain file, which is just a list of intermediate certificates.

  - Check that there are one or more certificates in it. Each certificate begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.